# Request migrations for questions on other sites?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled upon an (admittedly old and) answered [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951823/how-to-get-a-precise-ping-measurment) which I consider to have a better place here. Should and/or do we request migrations in such cases?

Comment: I thought SE policy was that old questions are not migrated no matter what. There's nothing stopping you (or anyone else ) from reasking the question here, though...

Answer (score 5):

Generally old questions (especially ones with answers) stay where they are so as not to break people's bookmarks.  It would suck if someone had a question that was answered on Stack Overflow, bookmarked it for future reference, and then comes back a few years down the road to find all the answers are gone and there's a big sign on the door saying "Go to this other site".

In this case the question is 3 years old - it's a good question but personally I'd let it stay where it is.
It seems happy :)

Comment: In any case, questions over 60 days old can't be migrated at all.